# Integral that converges but does not converge .

Tags: calculus

I am curios about the following integral:

\begin{equation}
\int_0^1  \frac{x^2-x-1}{(x-2)(x-1)^2} dx.
\end{equation}

You can try Wolfram Alpha, or Maxima and it will say that the integral does no converge. In fact you can show that it is $\left . \ln |x-2| - 1/(x-1)  \right |_0^1$, and you ca see the problems both in the log and in the $1/(x-1)$ fraction.   Still if you compare the integrand with the function $f(x)=x$, call the integrand $g(x)$. You find that 
$0 \le  g(x) < f(x)$ and $\int_0^1 f(x)=1/2$. so The integral
$\int_0^1 g(x)$ converges.  The [comparison test](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/ImproperIntegralsCompTest.aspx) justifies this as convergence.

So what is it, converges or does not converges?

Thanks.

Comment: "You find that..." - and yet, you did not notice that the function is singular at the right end, and thus needs to be handled specially? Here is an analogy you might appreciate: over $(-1,0)$, you have $-x>\frac1{x}$, and yet only the integral of $-x$ in that interval is finite.

Comment: Yes....how should I handle this integral?  Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think that $g(x)<x$? For $x$ close to $1$ the numerator is $-1+O(x-1)$ while the denominator is $O((x-1)^2)$, so the whole fraction is $O((x-1)^{-2}$ near $1$. Soon enough that will be far larger than $x$, indeed it should already be so by $x=3/4$.

Comment: What does the title mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Tertium non datur*:
$$\frac{x^2-x-1}{(x-2)(x-1)^2}=\color{red}{\frac{1}{(x-1)^2}}+\color{blue}{\frac{1}{x-2}}$$
and the red term has a non integrable singularity in a left neighbourhood of $x=1$, while the blue term is continuous over $[0,1]$, hence the integral is not converging.

Comment: it was typo sorry

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio : you are right but the comparison test says that if $0\le g(x) \le f(x)$  and $\int_a^b f(x)$ converges then $\int_a^b g(x)$ converges. Then I might not being interpreting the comparison test right.  I want to solve the contradition. I found that it diverges, but then using the comparison test I found that it converges. Where is the flaw? Thanks.

Comment: @HermanJaramillo: are you sure your $f(x)$ is integrable over $[0,1]$? What is your integrable upper bound? Our function cannot be less than $x$ over $[0,1]$, simply because $x$ is bounded while $\frac{1}{(x-1)^2}+\frac{1}{x-2}$ is not.

Comment: Just for illustration: [the upper bound of $x$ really does not hold](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5B+%7B(x%5E2-x-1)%2F((x-2)(x-1)%5E2),+x%7D,+%7Bx,0,1%7D+%5D&t=crmtb01).

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio :  $f(x)=x \ge   (x^2-x-1)/(x-2)(x-1)^2$. I plotted both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$  in gnuplot and they looked like $0  \le g(x) \le f(x)$ in $[0,1]$. I validated your answer but to tell you the true I am not yet satisfied until the contradiction with the test rule is solved. Thanks.

Comment: @HermanJaramillo: I think that Clement C.'s plot tells quite the opposite. And anyhow: how can a bounded function be pointwise greater than an unbounded one? Evaluate at $x=0.99999999$. Your inequality does not hold.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio :  $(x^2 - x- 1)/(x^3 - 4 x^2 + 5 x -2 ) \le x^3/x^2$

Comment: @HermanJaramillo: over $(0,1)$, that is not true. Again: evaluate at $0.9999999$. You need an integrable upper bound for $\left|\frac{x^2-x-1}{(x-2)(x-1)^2}\right|$.

Comment: @HermanJaramillo Have a look at the plot above. The inequality you base your comparison on does *not* hold... It does not even hold at a single point, actually: even at $x=0$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio : you are right. I will check my derivation of $g(x) \le f(x)$, I should have an error there.  Thanks.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio : Understand what you say. You say look at plot? I do not see any plots here.  I was fooled by a plot. I just showed analytically that the inequality is false.

Comment: @HermanJaramillo Look at the link in this comment for a plot: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1819639/integral-that-converges-but-does-not-converge#comment3718629_1819646